# Iterate over pattern grep function in R

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I am novice in R. I want to write the loop for the below code in R.

```
day1<-XYZ[, -grep("_0", colnames(XYZ))]
day2<-XYZ[, -grep("_0|_1", colnames(XYZ))]
day3<-XYZ[, -grep("_0|_1|_2", colnames(XYZ))]
day4<-XYZ[, -grep("_0|_1|_2|_3", colnames(XYZ))]
day5<-XYZ[, -grep("_0|_1|_2|_3|_4", colnames(XYZ))]
day6<-XYZ[, -grep("_0|_1|_2|_3|_4|_5", colnames(XYZ))]
day7<-XYZ[, -grep("_0|_1|_2|_3|_4|_5|_6", colnames(XYZ))]
day8<-XYZ[, -grep("_0|_1|_2|_3|_4|_5|_6|_7", colnames(XYZ))]
day9<-XYZ[, -grep("_0|_1|_2|_3|_4|_5|_6|_7|_8", colnames(XYZ))]
day10<-XYZ[, -grep("_0|_1|_2|_3|_4|_5|_6|_7|_8|_9", colnames(XYZ))]
day11<-XYZ[, -grep("_0|_1|_2|_3|_4|_5|_6|_7|_8|_9|_10", colnames(XYZ))]
day12<-XYZ[, -grep("_0|_1|_2|_3|_4|_5|_6|_7|_8|_9|_10|_11", colnames(XYZ))]
day13<-XYZ[, -grep("_0|_1|_2|_3|_4|_5|_6|_7|_8|_9|_10|_11|_12", colnames(XYZ))]
day14<-XYZ[, -grep("_0|_1|_2|_3|_4|_5|_6|_7|_8|_9|_10|_11|_12|_13", colnames(XYZ))]
day15<-XYZ[, -grep("_0|_1|_2|_3|_4|_5|_6|_7|_8|_9|_10|_11|_12|_13|_14", colnames(XYZ))]
day16<-XYZ[, -grep("_0|_1|_2|_3|_4|_5|_6|_7|_8|_9|_10|_11|_12|_13|_14|_15", colnames(XYZ))]
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `lapply` and create the subsets in a `list`

```
lst <- lapply(0:15, function(x) XYZ[, -grep(paste("_", 0:x, collapse="|",
          sep=""),  colnames(XYZ))])
names(lst) <- paste0("day", 1:16)
```

It is better not to create multiple objects in the global environments.  But, if we it is for exploration

```
i1 <- 0:15
for(i in seq_along(i1)) {
    assign(paste0("day", i), 
        value = XYZ[, -grep(paste("_", 0:i1[i], collapse="|", sep=""), colnames(XYZ))])
}
```

Comment: ,Thanks, it worked. Could you please tell me if I want to include two more columns such as "a","b" then how to put that into this code?

Comment: @User0590 In the first code, just do `cbind(XYZ[c("a", "b"), XYZ[, -grep(...`

Comment: In the second code, too the same you can replicate with `value = cbind(XYZ[c("a", "b"), XYZ[, -grep`

Comment: If I want to remove columns then value = cbind(XYZ[,-c("a", "b"), XYZ[.... Right?

Comment: @User0590 I thought you wanted to include it.  You can do `setdiff` i.e. `XYZ[setdiff(names(XYZ), c("a", "b", grep(paste(....), colnames(XYZ), value = TRUE)))]`

Comment: I want to remove "a","b". When I am running above code, it just giving "a","b" variables values as output.

Comment: @User0590  Not sure if you are running it correctly.  I used `setdiff` so that those variables are removed, along with `grep` I used 'value = TRUE` so that the column names are there for the `setdiff`

Comment: I can you tell me how to use SETDIFF in the 2nd code?. Thank you so much. I am novice in R.

Comment: @User0590  Just replace with `value = XYZ[, setdiff(names(XYZ), c("a", "b", grep(paste("_", 0:i1[i], collapse="|", sep=""), colnames(XYZ), value = TRUE)))])`

Comment: I have one more doubt. The above script is not working fine from day10-day15. It is having same variable fro day10-day15. I am using the same script.

Comment: @User0590 It is not clear when you say that it is not working. `paste0("day", 0:15)
 #[1] "day0"  "day1"  "day2"  "day3"  "day4"  "day5"  "day6"  "day7"  "day8"  "day9"  "day10" "day11" "day12" "day13" "day14"  "day15"`  If you look at the 'day' number string, it is exactly what is expected

Comment: @User0590 It is difficult to know without a reproducible example.  Can you replace the paste part with `paste0("\\b(", paste("_", 0:x, collapse="|", sep=""), ")\\b")`

Comment: Using below code: `i1 <- 0:15 for(i in seq_along(i1)) { assign(paste0("day", i), value = XYZ[, setdiff(names(XYZ),c("a","b", paste0("avg_temp.", XYZ[['city']][1]),grep(paste("_", 0:i1[i],collapse="|", sep=""), colnames(XYZ), value = TRUE)))]) }`.So, According to my requirement, for "Day14", it should not contain variable(column1_1,column2_2) name containing "_0","_1",......"_12","_13" and for Day15 it should not contain any variable name having "_0","_1",......"_12","_13","_14".. But other than these variables should contain every variable.

Comment: @User0590  But that requirment was not in your original post.  You may need to post a new question as this is a new requirement